# Truffle Contract transaction doesn't wait to be mined

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract

I have a thing that has been annoying me when using truffle-contract, ever since updating from Truffle 2 to Truffle 3.

I am no longer able to run transactions synchronously - even though it is stated on the Github page for truffle-contract that:

`}).then(function(result) {
    // This code block will not be executed until truffle-contract has verified
    // the transaction has been processed and it is included in a mined block.
    // truffle-contract will error if the transaction hasn't been processed in 120 seconds.
    //
    // Since we're using promises, we can return a promise for a call that will
    // check account two's balance.
    return coin.balances.call(account_two);`

When I run my client application:

https://pastebin.com/MbbL2bJt

It calls the `createAccount` function and then right after it calls the `setBalance` function, which causes the setBalance to fail since the account is not created before this happens.

This seems to me like it is the opposite of what the statement from truffle-contract says it will do.

If anyone can help, I'll be ever grateful

- Simon